# How to simplify negated SOP to SOP?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have the following boolean expression:

```
![ (ab!cd) + (!a!b!cd) + (!a!b!c!d) + (a!b!cd) + (!a!bcd) + (a!bcd) + (abcd) + (a!b!c!d)]
```

Notice how this is a canonical SOP but it is negated.

My first logical step to simplify it would be to apply De Morgans Law, but that will give me a POS.

Is there another way to simplify this and get a SOP?

Comment: Take other 8 combinations of negated/not-negated variables. Their disjunction will be a (canonical) SOP.

Answer (score 1):

You could visualize your expression using a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map):

[image]

Translating the three blocks leads to the simplified sum-of-products:

```
c!d + b!d + !ab
```

Each of the eight terms in squared brackets corresponds to one `0` cell in the map. The remaining eight cells have value `1` due to the outer negation.

Comment: This is the correct answer, a karnaugh map. Thanks for your help.